# How do I automatically assign the date i clicked on my calendar to a textbox

Tags: ms-access, calendar, vba

The first print is my calendar, already fully functioning. Upon clicking on any day (any rectangle that has a day in it) i'm redirected to "formteste" which is my second print. What i'd like to know is how can i get the value on the "data" textbox to be the date which i clicked on the calendar. For exemple, if i click on day 5 of february, id like the "date" textbox to be automatically "05/02/2019".

[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE7Iw.png)

[formteste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7diNL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of the day is saved on the calendar squares and the month/year on the combo boxes, then:
Create a public variable "varDay" as integer (create it ouside of the form, in a module); When you click any box from the calender it saves the day value to varDay; Create a Sub Form_Load for the form with the date; Do some VBA code, create a new variable "varDate"; Then you do something like - varDate = CStr(varDay) & "/" & CStr(Forms!formCalendar!month) & "/" & CStr(Forms!formCalendar!year); After this, the date will be saved as string to that variable; Assign the value to the box: Me.Data.Value = FormatDateTime(varDate, 2); (FormatDateTime puts the date string in the correct format, the 2 is for short date). Done